# How can i reduce my desktop scale

Tags: 22.04, display, display-resolution

*I'm new on ubuntu and my resolution is 1366x768 and scale for big for me. How can i reduce scale %100 to like a %75-80 ?*

***Thanks for helps and sorry for my English, have a nice day..***

Comment: You can do it as follows click on the right corner of your screen (if you didn´t change your view) and it opens a window where you can click on "settings" and from there choose screen to adjust the resolution.

Comment: My maximum resolution is 1366x768 and my question is about the scale thanks for help but its not the anwser'' for me :)

Answer (score 1):

***I think I solved my problem:***
I downloaded the Gnome Tweaks application from Ubuntu Software and changed the scaling factor from 1.00 to 0.75 in the fonts section, so everything got smaller and I reduced the Dock-Icon Size to 28 on the personalization page in Ubuntu's settings. In short, my screen is bigger now and I can fit more stuff.